# How to zoom and scroll imageView in android

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview, zooming

I know this question is discussed in details and I know and tried some solutions including "TouchImageView". But my problem is slightly different. I want to scroll image without the aid of motion, gesture or any touch event. I'm using ScrollView for this, thought it may solve the problem.

I'm using ZoomControlers widget and just caling the scaling function of imageView for zoom in and zoom out...

The problem is ScrollView doesn't responding... Any suggestions will be appreciated

Below is my code for XML and MainActivity class...

**activity_zoom_image.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/zoom"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:src="@drawable/eiff" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ZoomControls
        android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**OnCreat method of ZoomImage.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(new Zoom(this));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom_image);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    zoom = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls1);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.eiff);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            float x = image.getScaleX();
            float y = image.getScaleY();

            image.setScaleX((float) (x+1));
            image.setScaleY((float) (y+1)); 
        }
    });

    zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float x = image.getScaleX();
            float y = image.getScaleY();
            if (x <= 1 || y <= 1)
                return;
            image.setScaleX((float) (x-1));
            image.setScaleY((float) (y-1));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: @VishwaIyer Yes it is working.....Thats is Image goes out of secreen, and I have to scroll it to view it...

Answer (score 0):

try to use a external jar file , like pinchzoom.jar . just google it and u can find one and the instructions as wel.

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/04/update-pinch-to-zoom-example-and.html

here is the link ,try it out ...cheers

Comment: Please add comprehensive description to your answer. The answers with only reference links are highly discourages because such answer becomes useless when the link is no longer working !

Comment: @vinay.sasalatti Thankx...But I'ad already tried different liberaries and yes they worked... I want to know is my approach right to tacle with this problem, If Yes then what should I do to make it work...

Comment: @muak ,try changing your xml to this as given below .

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/zoom"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:src="@drawable/eiff" />
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ZoomControls
        android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it won't work....I use exact same XML but wrap it in a Relative Layout...Still no scrolling

Comment: hi, m not sure y its not working for u , but it runs perfect in my emulator.

Comment: Its okay I done this with TouchEvent....I'll really appreciate if you send me the source code of working functionality....